# Subversion - Compare two text files with custom extension

Tags: svn

Good Day,

I'm using an application that stores functions in a custom file extension (.mts).

For example I have subroutines located in functions.mts.  I'm using Subversion to store the changes made over the lifetime of this project.

Is there a way to customize Subversion so that I can diff the two files as if I was using C#?

TIA,

coson

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean as if the .mts files were themselves C++ files? If that's what you mean, Subversion doesn't have anything to do with it, because its internal diff only cares if a file is text or binary.

If you mean you want to use the same diff tool as your C++ IDE uses, you can configure Subversion (or identify on the command line) that you want to use an external tool for examining differences:

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externaldifftools

For instance, I have in my `~/.subversion/config` file this directive:

> diff-cmd = colordiff

This means that when I use `svn diff` I get colorized differences.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using diff exactly the same as with any other file? As far as I know it doesn't care about extension at all - you should be able to compare them like anything else.

I have tortoisesvn on this machine and selecting diff on two files with extension .test worked as expected.

Comment: I did do that.  I tried to compare the last two checkins for the file in question and I got a "Changed Files" dialog.  See http://www.omnicom-innovations.com/Images/QTP-Compare.png

Comment: Yes, I did.  I tried comparing the last two check-ins.  Oops.